# imprimir suma de matrices en java

Tags: java, array, matrices

Hellos ppl, vengo con una curiosidad, el codigo debajo funciona bien, si tengo los siguientes arrays:

```
         int [][] vec1 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
         int [][] vec2 = {{7,8,9},{10,11,12}};
```

Me da como resultado:

```
         [ 8 10 12 14 16 18 ]
```

entonces, mi pregunta seria esta: como podria imprimir en pantalla el resultado de una forma similar a esta:

```
     [ 8 10 12 ], [14 16 18]
```

ò

```
     [8 10 12 ]
     [14 16 18]
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

```
public class Prueba2{
public void sumaM (int[][] a, int[][]b){

   if(a.length == b.length){
       int[][] suma = new int[a.length][b[0].length];

       System.out.print("[ ");
       for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
           for(int j=0; j < a[i].length; j++){

               suma [i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
              System.out.print(suma[i][j]+ " ");
               //System.out.print(suma[j][i] + " ");

           }

        }
        System.out.println("]");

    }else{
       System.out.println("Las matrices no coinciden en tamaño");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Buen dia Barly

simplemente agrégale un salto de linea cuando acabe el segundo for, saludos!

```
public class Prueba2{
public void sumaM (int[][] a, int[][]b){

   if(a.length == b.length){
       int[][] suma = new int[a.length][b[0].length];

       System.out.print("[ ");
       for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
           for(int j=0; j < a[i].length; j++){

               suma [i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
              System.out.print(suma[i][j]+ " ");

           }
        System.out.println("],[");
        }
        System.out.println("]");

    }else{
       System.out.println("Las matrices no coinciden en tamaño");
    }

} 
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias men, con esto keda todo bien xDDD